# share saml token between webapi servers

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, saml-2.0, adfs2.0

I am developing a web application - the client is angularJS and the server is aps.net web api2 and adfs to authenticate.
I deploy my app on multiple servers (every server contain the whole app) and there is a network load balancer,
so the user (and the angularJS) contact the network load balancer.

When user enter the app, at first the server redirect him to authenticate and then the user can talk to the server.
My problem begin after the authentication, when the network load balancer redirect the user to other web api, then the "new" server doesnt know him and he cant get any data.

Is there any way to share the saml token between all my servers? 
how does resetful application can authenticate in cloud (like Amazon) , when the developer doesnt know how many server does he have or to what server the user contact?

thanks for helpers :)